# Cedilla under C (ç) in 'US international with dead keys' keyboard layout in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout

I prefer to use US international with dead keys keyboard layout in order to get Latin diacritics for characters like é, è, à, etc in Libreoffice in Linux Mint.

On this layout characters like ´, `, ^, " are **dead keys** (clicked once do nothing) that can be pressed before other letters in order to get these signs.

```
' with a gives á
` with a gives à
" with a gives ä
```

etc, but

```
' with c gives ć
```

**Can I get ç in this layout in Linux?**

---

In Windows I do not have 'US international with dead keys' but only 'US international' which seems identical, only there  dead-key `'` with `c` gives `ç` (in both MSOffice and LibreOffice), which I think is the expected behavior.

---

I had imagined this might be a all-around system-level problem in Linux. But [this](http://marin.jb.free.fr/qwerty-fr/) keyboard layout (mentioned in a comment by [user BramMooij](https://superuser.com/users/522652/brammooij) under [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1075998/162573)) can produce in Linux the cedilla under C (Ç) with AltGr-c.

Comment: Can't test specifically for US keyboard, but for me on International Eng simply alt/c gives ç - no dead key required

Comment: @Tetsujin - do you have the other diacritics in that layout, all the other French letters? Take a look at my other question please: http://superuser.com/q/1075998/162573

Comment: @Tetsujin - I'm afraid this is OS and application specific. I will update the question and give all details (about Linux). In Windows with MSOffice 2013 things are different.

Comment: That was the conclusion I was coming to too -  your dead keys are totally different to mine. Mine are e,u,i,n and ` for ´ ¨ ^ `and ~

Comment: @Tetsujin - this is because of the different keyboard layouts.

Comment: Potentially , and c might work.

Comment: @Aganju - `,` is not a dead key in *US-International with dead keys*

Comment: @Aganju - I want to give you credit for your comments that made me look deeper into this matter, and finally found it. I'll post as answer what I found.

Comment: This also works in Windows

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The key combination for `ç` in *US international with dead keys* layout was there all along, but unlike the other Latin diacritics it does not involve a dead key:

AltGr+,=ç

AltGr+Shift+,=Ç

[image]

Comment: My keyboard doesn't have the AltGr key. What can I do?

Comment: @FernandoSilveira normally it's just right alt

Comment: @YuriFeldman My keyboard doesn't have it. It has only the left Alt key.

Comment: Then maybe this thread can help - it proposes to install gnome-tweaks, and choose the alternative characters key from there
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030248/how-to-set-alternative-characters-key-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 38):

It's because the cedilla module isn't loaded by default when the locale is set to *en*, so you have to change the configuration files for gtk to add them:

**1. Edit configuration files:**

```
sudo vim /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache

sudo vim /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache
```

On both, find the lines starting with `"cedilla" "Cedilla"` and add :en to the line. Something like this:

`"cedilla" "Cedilla" "gtk30" "/usr/share/locale" "az:ca:co:fr:gv:oc:pt:sq:tr:wa:en"`

**2. Change the Compose file:**

```
sudo sed -i /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose -e 's/ć/ç/g' -e 's/Ć/Ç/g'
```

**3. Instruct the system to load the *cedilla* module:**

Add those lines to `/etc/environment`:

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla
QT_IM_MODULE=cedilla
```

Reboot and you are done.

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, I cross posted your answer on AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/30655/what-keyboard-layout-allows-me-to-type-%c3%a7/1113491#1113491
LMK if you want to post it yourself so I can remove my answer :)!

Comment: After some updates on the OS, this workaround stops working. Are there any permanent ways that aren't affected by updates?

Comment: There's no workaround that I know. As the changed files are part of the OS, any update will overwrite the files. You can create a `bash` script to alter the files again, so when you update, you can run the script again and change the files again.

Comment: How can I do that without root access, affecting only my user? I can't access root or run sudo commands :/

Comment: I've been using **only step 3** for this for a long time now and it always worked, probably since Ubuntu 18.04 (now I'm on Mint 21, based on Ubuntu 22.04). So I suggest you try step 3 alone and if it doesn't work, then you go for the other steps. Cheers!

Comment: Turns out it worked for **almost** everything without step 1 and 2. But then it didn't.

Comment: Since I've installed Ubuntu 23.04 this seems to work only for GTK2 and GTK3 apps, doesn't work for any GTK4.0 app. Anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 8):

If you like me don't have a <kbd>AltGr</kbd> button in your keyboard, try the following:

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

Comment: My Right Alt is `AltGr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `uim` as input manager with a `XCompose` file to reproduce the Microsoft Windows behavior for English international keyboards.

I've wrote some instructions for several distros (and even a Ubuntu package): https://github.com/raelgc/win_us_intl/

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple bash script following @ThoriumBR answer. This way, whenever there's an update to your system and you'll lose that config, you can just run the script again.

The script is idempotent, so feel free to run as many time as you want, the result won't change.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Setting vars up
COMPOSE_FILE='/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose'
GTK2_FILE='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache'
GTK3_FILE='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache'
ENV_FILE='/etc/environment'

# Backing up files
sudo cp ${COMPOSE_FILE} ${COMPOSE_FILE}.bak
sudo cp ${GTK2_FILE} ${GTK2_FILE}.bak
sudo cp ${GTK3_FILE} ${GTK3_FILE}.bak

# Fixing cedilla in Compose
sudo sed --in-place -e 's/ć/ç/g' ${COMPOSE_FILE}
sudo sed --in-place -e 's/Ć/Ç/g' ${COMPOSE_FILE}

# Fixing cedilla in GTK files
GTK_FILE_SEARCH_FOR='^"cedilla".*:en'
GTK_FILE_SED_EXP='s/^\(\"cedilla\".*:wa\)/\1:en/g'

grep -q ${GTK_FILE_SEARCH_FOR} ${GTK2_FILE}
[ $? -eq 1 ] && sudo sed --in-place -e ${GTK_FILE_SED_EXP} ${GTK2_FILE}
grep -q ${GTK_FILE_SEARCH_FOR} ${GTK3_FILE}
[ $? -eq 1 ] && sudo sed --in-place -e ${GTK_FILE_SED_EXP} ${GTK3_FILE}

# Fixing cedilla in environment file
ENV_FILE_GTK_LINE='GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla'
ENV_FILE_QT_LINE='QT_IM_MODULE=cedilla'

grep -q ${ENV_FILE_GTK_LINE} ${ENV_FILE}
[ $? -eq 1 ] && echo ${ENV_FILE_GTK_LINE} | sudo tee -a ${ENV_FILE} > /dev/null
grep -q ${ENV_FILE_QT_LINE} ${ENV_FILE}
[ $? -eq 1 ] && echo ${ENV_FILE_QT_LINE} | sudo tee -a ${ENV_FILE} > /dev/null
```

Then you can save it to a file such as `fix-cedilla.sh` and run it with `bash fix-cedilla.sh`. Or you can mark that file as executable with `chmod +x fix-cedilla.sh` and run it with `./fix-cedilla.sh`.

You can/should also add it to your dotfiles repo ([example of mine](https://github.com/lfilho/dotfiles/blob/main/bin/fix-cedilla-in-linux.sh)) so next time you (re)install your OS it's handy in a known place ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just open a terminal and execute the following to add the intended behaviour to `'+c` and `'+C`

`~/.XCompose`

```shell
echo '<dead_acute> <c>     : "ç"' >>~/.XCompose
echo '<dead_acute> <C>     : "Ç"' >>~/.XCompose
```

Reboot or alternatively restart GNome with `ALT+F2` then type `r+ENTER`.