# QWERTY keyboard layouts with French characters?

Tags: keyboard-layout, diacritics

I know about *US International with dead keys* that uses dead keys like ' ` ^ " before typing the letter with the diacritic.

Are there other QWERTY layouts with **all** French diacritic characters (à, â, é, è, ê, ê, ë, î, ï, ô, ù, û, ü, ç)?

---

### UPDATE:

It seems that the question is too broad in its initial form that said "Latin diacritics" beside "French characters": **some  QWERTY keyboards that have Latin characters with diacritics lack part of the French characters**. The *US International with dead keys* in Linux (*US international* in Windows) has all the French characters, but *US International AltGr dead keys* that I found in Linux has more Latin characters with diacritics while lacking essential French letters like `é`.

Comment: Could this maybe help you? http://marin.jb.free.fr/qwerty-fr/

Comment: @BramMooij - you should post this as an answer. In Linux Mint KDE was installed successfully and can be found as a variant of the English US layout

Comment: Good to know, when previously answering, I didn't have time to properly check out the website. I posted an answer, please let me know whether I should expand it.

Comment: @BramMooij - considering expanding the answer: I have tried to edit it to add those lines on what keys do what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This website](http://marin.jb.free.fr/qwerty-fr) hosts the keyboard layout you are looking for. There is a *.deb file, and Arch linux install, a Mac OS install and a Windows install available.

[image: The keyboard layout]

Comment: I will keep this open for a while, I'm curious for multiple solutions here.