# Cedilla with ' and c (dead key) for QT apps

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, kde, input-languages, qt

As a Brazilian, I want my american keyboard to use dead keys and to map cedilla (ç) to **' + c**. The default mapping gives me **ć**. For GTK-based applications, this setup can be easily achieved by setting the following environment variable:

```
GTK_IM_MODULES=cedilla
```

However, for Qt-based applications (like KWrite), the same method doesn't work:

```
QT_IM_MODULES=cedilla #doesn't work!
```

The Qt applications will continue to print ć. How do I debug and fix this?

Note: please, do not suggest the approach given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1075992/cedilla-under-c-%C3%A7-in-us-international-with-dead-keys-keyboard-layout-in-linu). Typing **AltGr + c** feels very alien to a Brazilian and the GTK solution works just fine.

Comment: Dies the solution described in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60884/how-to-make-compose-work-in-gtk-and-qt-apps/77473) work for you, to set `XMODIFIERS="@im=none"` to let X11 handle dead keys. See also this [Qt bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-9311).

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creating a file `~/.XCompose` with the following content should do the trick:

```
include "%S/en_US.UTF-8/Compose"
<dead_acute> <C>                        : "Ç"
<dead_acute> <c>                        : "ç"
```

However, this is working only if the application is reading the XCompose files (`/usr/share/X11/locale/...`). This is no X server setting but really depends on the application, see [Gilles answer on UNIX.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59989) for a method to find out if an application is reading these files.

Comment: Amazing! Since I'm not using Wayland, this is good enough for me.